# Selecting Random Method From Multiple Methods

Tags: java

I am trying to select a random method from the ones created inside the class. Is there a way to create an `ArrayList` and pass methods to it? I have attempted to do just that but I am getting an error when I try to add the method to the array.

```
public class Monkey{

    private int energy;

    String[] food = {"Meat", "Fish", "Bugs", "Grain"};
    ArrayList<Activity> monkeyActivity = new ArrayList<>();

    public Monkey(int energy) {
        this.energy = energy;
    }

    public int getEnergy() {
        System.out.println("Monkey energy level: " + energy);
        return energy;
    }

    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("Monkey: Oooo Oooo~!");
        energy -= 3;
        monkeyActivity.add(sound()); //I get an error message here when trying 
                                 //to add the method to the array
    }

    public void play(){
        if (energy >= 8){
            System.out.println("Monkey begins to play.");
            energy -= 8;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Monkey does not have enough energy to play");
        }
        System.out.println("Energy remaining: " + energy);
    }

    public void eat(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(food.length);
        System.out.println("Monkey beings to eat " + food[index]);
        energy += 5;
        System.out.println("Energy remaining: " + energy);
    }

    public void sleep(){
        System.out.println("Monkey is sleeping: Zzz...");
        energy += 10;
        System.out.println("Energy remaining: " + energy);
    }
}
```

This is the separate class I have made for the generic Activity..

```
public class Activity {

    private String sleep;
    private String eat;
    private String sound;
    private String play;

    public Activity(String sleep, String eat, String sound, String play) {
        this.sleep = sleep;
        this.eat = eat;
        this.sound = sound;
        this.play = play;
    }

    public String getSleep() {
        return sleep;
    }

    public String getEat() {
        return eat;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public String getPlay() {
        return play;
    }

    public void setSleep(String sleep) {
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void setEat(String eat) {
        this.eat = eat;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    public void setPlay(String play) {
        this.play = play;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot add methods to a collection but if you're using Java-8 you can define your `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Consumer<String>>` which means you can add functions that accept a single operand of type `String` and return `void` or `ArrayList<Supplier<String>>` to add functions that accept no input and return a type `String` but I don't know how that will fit into your current example.

Comment: @Aominè OP's methods have `Runnable` signature, not `Supplier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store each method as `Runnable`, as any "action" is no-arg void method satisfying `Runnable` functional interface:

```
List<Runnable> actions = Arrays.asList(this::sound, this::play, this::eat, this::sleep);
```

to execute random method, just:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
actions.get(rnd.nextInt(actions.size())).run();
```

Comment: Or just use switch and call appropriate method based on a random value without creating list.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up concepts.

## technical issues:

#### return value clash

> ```
> public void sound() {
>     // ...
>     monkeyActivity.add(sound());
> ```

The return value of your method `sound()` is *void* (which means *no return value*), but you try to add its (not existing) return value as element to the List. This is what your compiler complains about.

#### unintended recursion

> ```
> public void sound() {
>     System.out.println("Monkey: Oooo Oooo~!");
>     energy -= 3;
>     monkeyActivity.add(sound());
> ```

In the last line you do a *recursive call* which means you call exactly the  same method this code is in. If that happens unintended it almost ever results in a `StackOverflowError`.

## writing classes without proper analysis

You have a class `Activity`. 
But if you have a closer look this is not a *single* activity (as the classes name implies) but it is *all possible activities*.

As a result your collection `monkeyActivity` cannot hold *single activities* as elements.

Doing a wild guess I think what you wanted is more like this:

```
interface Activity{
  void do();
}

public class Monkey{
    private int energy;
    String[] food = {"Meat", "Fish", "Bugs", "Grain"};
    List<Activity> monkeyActivity = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...        
    public void sound() {
        monkeyActivity.add(new Activity(){
              public void do(){                
                System.out.println("Monkey: Oooo Oooo~!");
                energy -= 3;
              }
           }); 
    }
```